# Python Requests Post "trendmicro.com"

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to get python to make a post request  to "global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com". I've tried getting the cookie and adding it to the header's. I'm not getting the results I should be.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()


session = requests.Session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36',
"Host": "global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com"
}

response = session.get('https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/',verify=False, headers=headers)

cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()

domain = "http://hsdfsdfam.com"

url = 'https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/result.php'

payload = {'urlname': domain, 'getinfo': 'Check+Now'}


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36',
"Referer": "https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/result.php",
"Origin": "https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com",
"Host": "global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com"
}

result = session.post(url, params=payload, headers=headers, cookies=cookies,verify=False)

if result.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "lxml")
    matching_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='labeltitleresult')
    for div in matching_divs:
        print(div.content)
else:
    print('failed to get the page somehow, see: {}'.format(results.status_code))
```

Comment: I should be getting "Untested" in the matching_divs element.